# Code runs normally but Debug gives "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c, graph, codeblocks, void-pointers

I stepped into this problem while building a program that does various things with graphs.
I wrote the code in C using Code Blocks and if I run it normally (Through "Build and Run") the program "works" (It still is not finished), but if i try to run the code through the debugger it stops with a `Segmentation fault`. That's pretty strange.

Here are some extracts of my code in order to solve this problem, sorry for the mess:

main.c

```
FILE *file;
char *input = "input.txt";
file = fopen(input, "r"); // Open the file read-only
if(file != NULL){
    G = parse(file, F);        // Parse the graph
fclose(file);  // Close the file
```

Graph.h

```
struct TGraph {
    void **adj;
    int nodes_count;
};

typedef struct TGraph *Graph;
typedef enum GraphType {LIST, MATRIX} GraphType;

typedef Graph (*INITGRAPH)(int);
typedef void (*ADDADJ)(Graph, int, int, float);
typedef void (*PRINT)(Graph);

typedef struct funct{
    INITGRAPH init;
    ADDADJ addEdge;
    PRINT print;
}FunctGraph;

 typedef struct AdjList{  //I need this in order to use the adj as a List
    List *nodes;
}AdjList;
```

Graph.c

```
Graph initGraphList(int nodes_count){
    Graph G = malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
    ((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(List)); <<< PROBLEM HERE
    G->nodes_count = nodes_count;
    return G;
}
```

Graphparser.c

```
Graph parse(FILE *file, FunctGraph *F){   
    Graph G = NULL;
    puts("Controllo numero di nodi...");
    if (!match(file, LPAR)){     // Check if number of nodes is present
        syntax_error(errorsymb(LPAR), file);
    }else{
        fseek(file,1,SEEK_CUR);     //Going over the LPAR
        G = parse_init(file, F->init); //Initialize the Graph <<< PROBLEM HERE
        if (G == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'allocazione del grafo\n");
            exit(1);
        }else{
            if (!match(file, RPAR))
                syntax_error(errorsymb(RPAR), file);
            else{                    // If so parse the graph
                fseek(file,1,SEEK_CUR);
                printf("Rilevato grafo da %d nodi\n", G->nodes_count);
                puts("Costruisco il grafo...");
                while(!match(file, DOT)){
                    read_node(G, file, F->addEdge);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return G; // return the parsed Graph
}

int match(FILE *file, type et)
{
    // Try to match symbol of expected type 'et' in file
    // [returns 1 if successful, 0 otherwise]
    char c;
    type rp;                       // Type of the symbol read
    int res=0;
    while(((c = fgetc(file)) == '\t') || (c == '\n') || (c == ' ')); // Skip intitial tabulation, newline and spaces
    switch(c) {        // Determine the read symbol type
        case ',':
            rp = COMMA; break;
        case '(':
            rp = LPAR; break;
        case ')':
            rp = RPAR; break;
        case '.':
            rp = DOT; break;
        case '-':
            rp = MINUS; break;
        case '>':
            rp = ARROW; break;
        case ';':
            rp = SEMICOL; break;
        default :
            rp = NODEID; break;
    }
    ungetc(c,file);   // Push the characters read back to the file
    if (rp==et)        // The expexted type et and the read symbol type rp match
        res = 1;
    return res;
}

Graph parse_init(FILE *file, INITGRAPH init){
    unsigned int nodes;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &nodes);
    if(nodes >= INT_MAX)
        syntax_error("Numero nodi troppo grande", file);
    return init(nodes); // Initialize the graph
}
```

I think this should be all the code we need to find this problem.
As I marked within the code the problem lays in this row:

```
((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(List));
```

here the debugger calls the "Segmentation fault", but i can't see why.
Do you have any ideas why the code runs without the debugger and not with it, giving that error?
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Graph G = malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(List));
```

You are allocating memory with `malloc` for `G` but you never initlize it with valid values, so dereferencing `G->adj` will cause undefined behaviour. It seems to work in the release but not in debug build.

If you are using Visual Studio, the debug build will initialize the memory usually with (I think `0xFE` or something, so it will crash when you dereference the pointer. In release build this is not happening, so it has some random address which apparently doesn't cause any immediate problems. Not sure if gcc also does this.

What you need is something like:

```
Graph G = malloc(sizeof(struct TGraph));
G->adj = malloc(whatever);
G->node_count = 0;
etc.
((AdjList *)(G->adj))->nodes = malloc(nodes_count * sizeof(List));
```

Comment: I tried to use your suggestions allocating this way: 'G->adj = malloc(sizeof(AdjList *))' because want to cast it as an 'AdjList *' later.
The debugger doesn't stop there but i receive another 'Segmentation fault' when trying to access elements of the List.
I think that there still is a problem with my allocations.

Comment: @Baum

The problem is that i have to create a Graph structure that can support both list and matrices of adjacency, in order to do that the teacher taught us to use 'void *' pointers, in order to cast that element with either of those methods.

Is there a way to make sure that 'G->adj' does point to a valid 'AdjList" (Or 'AdjMatrix') object?

Of course thanks to you both for your time in helping me.

Comment: You must allocate enough space that can hold the desired number of elements for the bigger of your structures. To make it more maintainable a union might be a good idea, because then you can adress any of the elements as you want without casting it and the sizeof will give you the correct size either.